# Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack resolution

Tags: java, jsp, security, xss, client-side-attacks

We have developed a new application, and before moving the changes we did a static scan of code using checkmarx.
There is a medium level vulnerablity that is found in the code named Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack.

This is detacted at first line of the JSP page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Can you please help me understand this attack and what should be done to eliminate this?

Comment: First step is to look these names up and find the reference on the OWASP website: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting

Comment: More info is needed regarding your page. Cross Frame Scripting isn't a real web vulnerability. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365297/frame-onkeydown-feedback).

Answer (score 5):

The *Client Cross Site Scripting Attack* query finds if the page protects itself against being embedded in an IFrame. It searches for conditions such as:

```
 if (top != self)
 if (top.location != location)
 if (top.frames.length != 0)
```

and so on.

This specific file, I believe, has no such conditions, so it MOST LIKELY does not protect itself, and this is why the query has found and marked it. Since we are looking for a missing line here, the result just shows you the file, and cannot show you where the problem is.

Hope it helps,

Adar from [Checkmarx](https://www.checkmarx.com).

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following piece of code in your HTML file.

```
<style id='antiClickjack'>
    body{display:none !important;}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (self === top) {
    var antiClickjack = document.getElementById('antiClickjack');
    antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
    } else {
    top.location = self.location;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For more depth to this issue, and to actually fix the Cross-Frame Scripting problem check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/

Basically throw this into your parent-most layout file (_Layout.cshtml in C# MVC)

```
        (function (window) { // Prevent Cross-Frame Scripting attacks
            if (window.location !== window.top.location)
                window.top.location = window.location;
        })(this);
```